# Get Period Date of DateTime after midnight - SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

We have a business rule which a day runs 5am - 5am. This means that in our database, if we have a sale coming in on '2019-01-05 02:00:00' that this has a 'PeriodDate' or 2019-01-04.

I am trying to make a view which gets a sum of SaleAmount over one day but at the moment, i am just getting the standard 12am - 12am day using the following code.

```
select Convert(date, dbo.Sales.[Time Stamp]) as PeriodDate, sum(Sales.[SalesAmount]) as SalesAmount, siteid from sales
group by Convert(date, dbo.Sales.[Time Stamp]), siteid
```

What i need to happen in to group sales by the correct PeriodDate (5am - 5am).

n.b. The column Time Stamp is a DateTime column which i why i originally converted it to a Date.

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL Server, correct? Which version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract 5 hours from `[Time Stamp]` and then convert to `date` before grouping:

```
select 
  convert(date, dateadd(hour, -5, [Time Stamp])) as PeriodDate, 
  sum([SalesAmount]) as SalesAmount, 
  siteid 
from sales
group by 
  convert(date, dateadd(hour, -5, [Time Stamp])), 
  siteid
```

Comment: One thing that might make processing a bit faster would be to nest your `CONVERT()` in a subquery and then you can use aggregation on `PeriodDate` without having to `CONVERT()` twice.

Comment: Thats Perfect thank you @forpas. And i will add in the subquery to speed up the processing Time Shawn. Thanks Team

Comment: @JoshFletcher  Two other notes: 1) Use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql 2) If you stay with `datetime`, it rounds to 3 thousandths of a milisecond. So, depending on how you take a timestamp, if an order comes in at `04:59:59.998`, it will get rounded to `05:00:00.000` and be `sum()`ed in the wrong day.